# Check whether NSF File is Password Protected or Not using C#.Suggest some dll to access NSF file without Domino Server installed

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I want to access NSF File using C#.
I am using Lotus Notes 8.5 ( **Not using Domino server** )

I am putting set of nsf files in a list.But before adding it in into list i want to **check whether it is password protected or not**.

How can i check that? **And how can i get password value**?

**Suggest me dll file which i can i use in current context**.

Comment: wow... 10+ questions on the front from you about lotus-notes ... busy as a bee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no DLL that you can use to access an NSF without Notes installed.  I guess if you're only concern is that Domino Server is not installed, well, then just install the Notes client.  But that's probably not what you mean.  If you want to access an NSF programmatically, you'll need to have the client or server installed.

To answer the question of whether an NSF is password protected, you'll need a Notes ID that has access rights on the server or local client.  You can get a handle to the database using NotesDatabase.Open, then use the db.QueryAccess("-Default-") method to determine what the access level is for the default user.  That will tell you what the default access level is for all users no matter who they are.

Answer (score 0):

Preeti,
You might read on domino principles first, making it easier for you to understand. Notes databases are not password protected. However Notes databases have Access level and can be encrypted. You need an installed Notes client and a Notes.id (or access to a Domino server with the NSF on it). If the database has been encrypted (which is most likely the default for any sensible organization) you must have the exact ID the database was encrypted with.
As Ken pointed out db.QueryAccess can be used to check access rights. You might want to check, besides -Default- also the current user's rights.